# PLSQL Function that doesn't raise exception properly

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, exception

I am writing a function that is to return a student's name when an ID is entered. If an ID is entered, that doesn't exist in the database, I want an exception to be raised. Instead when I enter incorrect Student IDs it either returns nothing if I have the basic exception thrown OR returns this error message with an exception declared:

```
6503. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Function returned without value"
*Cause:    A call to PL/SQL function completed, but no RETURN statement was
       executed.
*Action:   Rewrite PL/SQL function, making sure that it always returns
       a value of a proper type.
```

Here's my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function STUDENT( S_NUM IN NUMBER)
RETURN varchar2 IS
STUDENT_NAME varchar2(50);
NOTEXISTS   EXCEPTION;
   cursor S_CUR is
   SELECT S_NAME
      FROM ROSTER
      WHERE S_NUM = S_ID;
BEGIN
   open S_CUR;
   fetch S_CUR into STUDENT_NAME;

   if S_CUR%notfound then
      RAISE NOTEXISTS;
   end if;
   close S_CUR;
RETURN STUDENT_NAME;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NOTEXISTS THEN -- handle the error
      dbms_output.put_line('NO STUDENT FOUND.');
END;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to `RAISE` an exception in the `when` part

Comment: Or a RETURN statement, e.g., RETURN NULL;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an exception occurs, you are not returning the actual error message.Your function is supposed to return varchar. However you are only just printing the error and not returning the actual error message.

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN NOTEXISTS THEN -- handle the error
      dbms_output.put_line('NO STUDENT FOUND.');
      return 'No Student Found'
END;
```

Comment: Yes, thats usually for debugging and making sure the code gets there

Answer (score 1):

First, rather than define your own exception which is only valid within the context of your function, use the standard exception which is defined for this situation - the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function STUDENT(S_NUM IN ROSTER.S_ID%TYPE)
    -- Exceptions: raises NO_DATA_FOUND if the student ID passed in
    --             parameter S_NUM is not found in the STUDENT table.
    RETURN ROSTER.S_NAME%TYPE
IS
  STUDENT_NAME ROSTER.S_NAME%TYPE;
  bData_found  BOOLEAN;

 CURSOR S_CUR IS
   SELECT S_NAME
      FROM ROSTER
      WHERE S_NUM = S_ID;
BEGIN
  OPEN S_CUR;

  FETCH S_CUR INTO STUDENT_NAME;

  bData_found := S_CUR%NOTFOUND;

  CLOSE S_CUR;

  IF bData_found THEN
    RETURN STUDENT_NAME;    
  ELSE
    RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
  END IF;
END STUDENT;
```

Secondly, don't handle the exception in your function. The purpose of an exception is to allow the code to communicate an exceptional condition to other code. Let the caller handle the exception, as in:

```
DECLARE
  nStudent_id      ROSTER.S_ID%TYPE := 12345;
  strStudent_name  ROSTER.S_NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
  strStudent_name := STUDENT(nStudent_id);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('S_ID=' || nStudent_id || '  NAME=' || strStudent_name);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO STUDENT FOUND.');
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Agreed, up to a point. A function SHOULD handle its own, function-specific or application-specific errors, even if it's just to raise an error and pass it to the caller. For example, if student ID's should be no greater than 45999, then the function can have its own EXCEPTION to alert the caller when the user inputs 60444.